# Issue in positioning the D3 chart in the specified location wrapped in angular2

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, d3.js, angular, charts

I am facing some issues in positioning the chart and changing the color for the circles inside the bubble chart. I need to draw a bubble chart wrapped in the angular2 component by consuming some json content. I am facing some issues in positioning of the chart within the specified space/region.

Please refer the snapshot for the layout of the application. In the application based on some user clicks event, the bubble chart should be loaded just below, but currently it is loading way below the page i.e. below the entire page layout. This bubble chart is configured with route in angular2 and it is expected to be loaded in the router-outlet tag specified, but it is loading outside that [image]

Note: 
1. D3.js is used to draw the bubble chart which is wrapped in angular2 component.
2. I tried reducing the width and the height of the chart component, but still it is not rendered in the desired location.

[image]

HTML for the chart where it should be rendered

```
<div class="container" style="overflow:scroll; height:100%; width:100%;">
    <h2>Redis Administration</h2>
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
        <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#ExtractorQueue" [routerLink]="['./']">ExtractorQueue</a></li>
        <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#Extractor" [routerLink]="['Extractor']">Extractor</a></li>
        <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#Schedule" [routerLink]="['Schedule']">Schedule</a></li>
        <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#CacheVisualization" [routerLink]="['CacheVisualization']">Cache Visualization</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="tab-content">
        <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </div>
</div>
```

D3 wrapped in angular2 component code

```js
import { Component, ViewEncapsulation } from '@angular/core';
import { HTTP_PROVIDERS, Http } from '@angular/http';
import { Configuration } from '../Configuration/Configuration';

declare var d3: any;

@Component({
    selector: 'bubble-chart',
    styleUrls: ['css/BubbleChart.css'],
    providers: [Configuration, HTTP_PROVIDERS],
    template: ``,
    encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None 
})
export class BubbleChart {
    public resultData: any;
    public chartData: any;
    margin = 5;
    diameter = 660;

    constructor(private _Configuration: Configuration) {
        console.log("In constructor of BubbleChartComponent");
        this.DrawBubbleChart();
    }

    private DrawBubbleChart(): void {
        console.log("Inside DrawBubbleChart in BubbleChartComponent");
        //console.log(this.resultData);

        var color = d3.scale.linear()
            .domain([-1, 5])
            .range(["hsl(152,80%,80%)", "hsl(228,30%,40%)"])
            .interpolate(d3.interpolateHcl);

        var pack = d3.layout.pack()
            .padding(2)
            .size([this.diameter - this.margin, this.diameter - this.margin])
            .value(function (d) { return d.size; })

        var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
            .attr("width", this.diameter)
            .attr("height", this.diameter)
            .append("g")
            .attr("transform", "translate(" + this.diameter / 2 + "," + this.diameter / 2 + ")");

        var chart = d3.json(this._Configuration.BLUESKYDATACACHEAPI_GETEXTRACTORQUEUESLATEST, (error, root) => {
            if (error) throw error;

            var focus = root,
                nodes = pack.nodes(root),
                view;

            var circle = svg.selectAll("circle")
                .data(nodes)
                .enter().append("circle")
                .attr("class", function (d) { return d.parent ? d.children ? "node" : "node node--leaf" : "node node--root"; })
                .style("fill", (d) => { return d.children ? color(d.depth) : null; })
                .on("click", (d) => { if (focus !== d) zoom.call(this, d), d3.event.stopPropagation(); });

            var text = svg.selectAll("text")
                .data(nodes)
                .enter().append("text")
                .attr("class", "label")
                .style("fill-opacity", function (d) { return d.parent === root ? 1 : 0; })
                .style("display", function (d) { return d.parent === root ? "inline" : "none"; })
                .text(function (d) { return d.name; });

            var node = svg.selectAll("circle,text");

            d3.select("body")
                .style("background", "white")
                //.style("background", color(-1))
                .on("click", () => { zoom.call(this, root); });

            zoomTo.call(this, [root.x, root.y, root.r * 2 + this.margin]);

            function zoom(d) {
                var focus0 = focus; focus = d;

                var transition = d3.transition()
                    .duration(d3.event.altKey ? 7500 : 750)
                    .tween("zoom", (d) => {
                        var i = d3.interpolateZoom(view, [focus.x, focus.y, focus.r * 2 + this.margin]);
                        return (t) => { zoomTo.call(this, i(t)); };
                    });

                transition.selectAll("text")
                    .filter(function (d) { return d.parent === focus || this.style.display === "inline"; })
                    .style("fill-opacity", function (d) { return d.parent === focus ? 1 : 0; })
                    .each("start", function (d) { if (d.parent === focus) this.style.display = "inline"; })
                    .each("end", function (d) { if (d.parent !== focus) this.style.display = "none"; });
            }

            function zoomTo(v) {
                var k = this.diameter / v[2]; view = v;
                node.attr("transform", function (d) { return "translate(" + (d.x - v[0]) * k + "," + (d.y - v[1]) * k + ")"; });
                circle.attr("r", function (d) { return d.r * k; });
            }//end zoomTo

        });//end chart

    }//end DrawBubbleChart

}
```

Comment: Seems like the chart is drawn as SVG outside the Angular2 root element. Your code doesn't show how you integrate D3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution for this problem. Since D3 along generates the svg tags away from the specified location, it is better to use the nativeElement to force the D3 to generate the chart in the specified location. by this way we enforce D3 to generate in the specified DOM element placed in the specific locaiton

```
  var svg = d3.select(this.el.nativeElement).append("svg")
            .attr("width", (this.diameter + 800))
            .attr("height", this.diameter)
            .attr('id', 'mySVG')
            .append("g")
            .attr("transform", "translate(" + this.diameter / 2 + "," + this.diameter / 2 + ")");
```